# Unable to reload ActiveX control in Windows CE 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, activex, windows-ce

I am developing an ActiveX control targeted at Windows CE 6 (on a Motorola Workabout Pro 4, if specifying helps). I have stage one working, in the sense that I can compile in Visual Studio, and have deploy using a simple `CAB` file.

However, I am finding it very hit and miss as to whether I can update the control on the device. If I perform a clean rebuild (ensuring that all intermediary files are removed beforehand) and redeploy the CAB file, I find that any changes aren't reflected in the deployed code: The output is unchanged, both in IE on the device, and when connecting and debugging via the Visual Studio 2008. Secondly, any breakpoints that I have added in the debugger no longer hit.

If I manually replace the `dll` file, this still has no effect. Even stranger, the control *still* continues to work if I completely remove the `dll`!

I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to WinCE and ActiveX development, so any hints as to what I am missing here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, my problem was that I was failing to correctly register my `dll` with `COM`.

The simplest solution was for me to change the `CAB` file so that the the `dll` self-registered. In my case, this was done by changing a parameter in the `CAB` file properties for the `dll` in Visual Studio. This results in `<parm name="SelfRegister" />` being added to the `CAB` `_setup.xml` file:

```
...
<characteristic type="%CE2%" translation="install">
  <characteristic type="MakeDir" /> 
  <characteristic type="output.dll" translation="install">
    <characteristic type="Extract">
      <parm name="Source" value="OUPUT~1.002" /> 
      <parm name="SelfRegister" />
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
</characteristic>
...
```